# javascript new self invoking function

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I've got a question about self invoking functions in javascript.

What I'm doing is something similar to the following

```
myNamespace =  {}; //namespace for holding any objects/functions 

//helpModule as an example

myNamespace.HelpModule = new (function(){
    this.abc = '123';
    //lots of other code in here...
})();
```

now I'm able to access properties of myNamespace.HelpModule like so:

```
alert(myNamespace.HelpModule.abc);
```

But for starters jsLint doesn't like that saying "Weird construction. Delete 'new'.",
And this [page](http://sweatte.wordpress.com/javascript-optimization/javascript-best-practices) states that you shouldn't use Function Constructor, although in this case I'm not sure if its using the Function Constructor since its a self invoking function?

Anyway, it seems to work fine, and the reason I'm using it is to have "this" scope to the function instead of the global object (window). I could just defining it as an object literal or do something similar to

```
myNamespace.HelpModule = (function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.abc = '123';

    return obj;
}();
```

but neither of these seem as "elegant" to me.

I'm wondering if this is bad form/practice?

Comment: Cool way of defining modules, never seen that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is weird because the purpose of defining a constructor is to be able to reuse it to create many objects.

For your purpose, you can use this construct-

```
myNamespace.HelpModule = (function(){
    //private stuff here
    var a = 100;
    return {
        //public stuff here
        b : 200,
        something: function() {
            return a + this.b;
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Hmm yeah that's sort of similar to my second code example, but more elegant. But the problem I have with object literals is, say for example using jQuery I want to bind some events to the object using $.bind I would have to wait until after the object is defined, and in your case would have to do $(myNamespace.HelpModule).bind('myEvent', function(){ etc.. }); after the self invoking function. So its not a nicely self contained piece of code